# Why is my application throwing a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am starting to work on three classes at once and while doing so i have received the error message above. I am very confused on why it is showing. I'm new to java so it could be something very easy that i just can't see. I am getting the error on the shopping cart class under the addToCart method. I know this is  alot of stuff to look at but i would really appreciate any and all help that i can get.

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    private int itemCount;     //total number of items in the cart 
    private double totalPrice;     //total price of items in the cart 
    private final int MAXSIZE = 100; // cart maximum capacity 
    private Item[]cart;

    //creates an empty shopping cart 
    public ShoppingCart()
    {
       Item[]cart = new Item [MAXSIZE];
       itemCount = 0;
       totalPrice = 0.0;
    }

    //adds an item to the shopping cart
    public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
    {

        cart[itemCount] = new Item(itemName, price, quantity);
        totalPrice = (totalPrice + (quantity * price)); 
        itemCount++;

    }
    //returns the contents on the cart together with summary information
    public String toString()
    {
        String contents = "\nShopping Cart\n";
        contents = contents + String.format("%-12s%-12s%-10s%-7s%n", "Item",
        "Unit Price", "Quantity", "Item Total");

        for(int i = 0; i<itemCount; i++)
        contents = contents + cart[i].toString() + "\n";

        contents = contents + String.format("%20s$ %.2fn","CurrentTotal:", totalPrice);

        return contents;
    }

}













import java.util.*;

public class Shop
    {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        ShoppingCart myCart = new ShoppingCart();
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);




        String itemName;
        double itemPrice;
        int quantity;

        String keepShopping = "y";

        do 
        {
            System.out.print ("Enter the name of the item: "); 
            itemName = kbd.nextLine();

            System.out.print ("Enter the unit price: ");
            itemPrice = kbd.nextDouble();

            System.out.print ("Enter the quantity: ");
            quantity = kbd.nextInt();

            myCart.addToCart(itemName, itemPrice, quantity);

            System.out.print ("Continue shopping (y/n)? ");
            keepShopping = kbd.next();
            kbd.nextLine();
        }
        while (keepShopping.equals("y"));

        System.out.println("Have a Nice Day!");

    }
}










import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Item
{
    private String name;
    private double unitPrice;
    private int quantity;

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create a new item with the given attributes.
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    public Item (String itemName, double itemPrice, int numPurchased)
    {
        name = itemName;
        unitPrice = itemPrice;
        quantity = numPurchased;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    //   Return a string with the information about the item
    // -------------------------------------------------------

    public String toString ()
    {
        return String.format("%-15s$%-8.2f%-11d$%-8.2f", name, unitPrice, quantity,     unitPrice*quantity);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    //   Returns the unit price of the item
    // -------------------------------------------------
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    //   Returns the name of the item
    // -------------------------------------------------
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    //   Returns the quantity of the item
    // -------------------------------------------------
    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: because when i did it said it wasnt formatted correctly. and what ever i did, didnt work so i had to post pictures

Comment: if it's a lot to look at, please do the work for us: undo your changes until you don't get the error, and then work in a single class, adding your changes in until you hit the error again: the last thing you added caused the error and you should start debugging from there

Comment: You can, at least, post the stacktrace. No need to format that.

Comment: ill just try to figure it out.. thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace. I just looked over the classes and they seem fine. I have a suspicion about the way you are reading in the values though - it is looking for the input in the next line but you are reading it in the same line (as System.out.print does not return a new line)

Comment: i'm sorry, apparently the first time that i spaced it by four it wasn't spaced by 4? lol. anyway i fixed it. i'm sorry for everyone's frustrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are [declaring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) the `cart` array

```
private Item[]cart;
```

inside this constructor, you are initializing it

```
public ShoppingCart()  {
   Item[]cart = new Item [MAXSIZE];
   itemCount = 0;
   totalPrice = 0.0;
}
```

but when you attempt to access one of its elements here (`cart[itemCount]`) it throws a `NullPointerException`

```
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)  {
    cart[itemCount] = new Item(itemName, price, quantity);
    totalPrice = (totalPrice + (quantity * price));
    itemCount++;
}
```

This is because, although you are declaring the array properly, it goes right back to `null` as soon as the constructor is over. The [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) of that instance is local to the constructor body itself.

Change

```
Item[] cart = new Item [MAXSIZE];
```

to

```
cart = new Item [MAXSIZE];
```

Then,

```
cart[itemCount] = new Item(itemName, price, quantity);
```

will no longer throw a `NullPointerException`, because `cart`'s scope has been expanded to the entire class.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't check it right now because I'm at work but. I'm sure you know what you're talking about. Thank you to everyone who replied

Answer (score 0):

You get the NullPointer exception if you are trying to reference a variable that has not been declared/instantiated. For instance if you declared something like:
List newList;
Then tried doing:
newList.add(item);
It would thrown an exception because new list was never instantiated. If it is throwing it in the addToCart() function it is most likely because one of the variables you are using has not been declared or instantiated. I would debug and print out the value of each variable when you get to that function call to make sure they have a value associated with them. If they don't that may just be your problem.